# Is there a way to make a base64 encoded background image png black and white on hover with css only?

Tags: css, base64, png, background-image

I didn't found a solution for that problem. It seems possible if you use svgs with grayscale filters but is there an easy way to do this with css only?

**Update:**

```
filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

and

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
filter: grayscale(0%);
```

Works for newest Firefox and Chrome versions.

Answer (score 0):

May you wrap the image into an div.
Then hide an show the image. And change the color of the div.

example for the css:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

here the working example, hope it is what you want:
https://jsfiddle.net/3v4on7cv/

```
#testDiv:hover > img
```

is the needed css selector, it will select all parent images of the hovered element with id "testDiv"

Comment: Thx, but not an Option. The divs are bigger than the Logos and I would like the background to stay white, only remove the color so that the logo displays as gray.

Answer (score 0):

If you have managed to set the background image data with a base64 string then just do it again for :hover with black and white data.

Comment: Thx, but I want a small css file and there are a lot of logos. So a simple css trick to remove the color on hover would be a way better option than to double my css file size ;)